# Publish JSON data into a date based table using Flask Jinja2 template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have JSON data that I want to publish on a webpage in a table format. I'm stuck to validate dates in the jinja template as few dates are missing and data needs to be published under those dates only for which data is available.

JSON DATA I HAVE:
https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/appointment/sessions/public/calendarByPin?pincode=241301&date=21-05-2021

[PAGE VIEW I WANT][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfVnT.png

MY CODE:

```
<tbody>
  {% for center in centers %}
    <tr>                      
      <th scope="row">
        <address>
          {{ center['name'] }} <br>
          {{ center['address'] }}
        </address>
      </th>
      {% for date in dates %}
        {% if date == center["sessions"][dates.index(date)]["date"] %}
          <td>
            {{ center["sessions"][dates.index(date)]["available_capacity"] }} <br>
            {{ center["sessions"][dates.index(date)]["min_age_limit"] }} <br>
            {{ center["sessions"][dates.index(date)]["vaccine"] }} <br>
          </td>
        {% else %}
          <td>None</td>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
     </tr>
   {% endfor %}
 </tbody>
```

I have got a solution to this problem. I can preformat data in a new python dictionary rather than direct pushing raw JSON data to the Jinja template, but I'm keener to understand if we can apply any other approach.

Answer (score 1):

You should not add much logic into templates.

There are a few reasons for this:

- Best practices. Single responsibility principle.
- Good design - application logic independent from the view logic.
- Prevent illegible, hard to understand and maintain implementation.
- Save your future you from a lot of effort

To be able to do something, especially in a language like Python that allows to mix and go very deep and complex (and even ugly) if you want to, does not mean you should.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I'll follow the best practices.